# Controller Method not being called Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, laravel

I have a Form that contains a Dropdown and a Submit button. Like so:

View path: webmasters/filters.blade.php

```
 {{ Form::open() }}
  {{ Form::select('filt', $Dropdown, 2) }}
  {{ Form::Submit('Filter') }}
 {{ Form::close() }}
```

And a controller that populates the Dropdown with values queried from a DB. Like so:

Controller name: WebController.php

```
 class WebController extends BaseController {
   public function getFilters() {
     $filters = Dropdown::getFilters();
     return View::make('webmasters.filter',['Dropdown'=>$filters]);
   }

   public function postFilters() {
     $filt = Input::get('name'); // getting the value of the select
     $filters = Dropdown::getFilters();
     $query = DB::table('webmasters.top_pages')->where('filter',$filt)->limit(20)->get();
     return View::make('webmasters.filter', array('query'=>$query),['Dropdown'=>$filters]);
   }

 }
```

Here is my route:

```
 Route::resource('topPage', 'WebController@getFilters');
```

getFilters is a model method that queries the DB for the values that come into the dropdown.

**EDIT**

My View file:

```
 {{ Form::open() }}
 <p></p>
 <table class='liste' style='margin-left: 0px;' cellpadding='5'> 
 {{ Form::select('name', $Dropdown) }}
 <div>
 {{ Form::Submit('Filter') }}
 </div>
    <tr>
        <td style='background-color: #426bb3; color: white; font-weight: bold; width:16%;'>Datum</td>
        <td align='left' style='background-color: #426bb3; color: white; font-weight: bold; width:12%;'>Page</td>
        <td align='left' style='background-color: #426bb3; color: white; font-weight: bold; width:12%;'>Kategorie</td>

    </tr>   
    @foreach($Webmasters as $topPages)
    <tr>
        <td> {{$topPages->date}} </td>              
        <td> {{$topPages->page}} </td>        
        <td> {{$topPages->category}} </td>  
        </tr>     
    @endforeach   
    </table><br>  
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I would like to call a controller method upon submitting the form so that the said method queries another DB and returns a table (on the same page as the dropdown and submit button) based on the selected value of the dropdown.

Since the default Form created using **Form::post()** is using POST, i figured i could access the value of the select using the second method in my controller **postFilters()**. This method goes ahead and uses the value as a where-clause as it queries anther DB and passes the results onto a View.
The Problem is, the View is not loading. I suppose i'm doing something wrong on the routing??
Can someone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "the view is not loading"? do you get an error message? a blank screen?

Comment: Hi @lukasgeiter. Thanks for your response from yesterday. Well, the screen already contains the Dropdown and Submit button, but i dont get the table that is supposed to have been passed on from the second Controller Method. So its not blank per se, just doesnt change.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of `filters.blade.php`? Or at least the part of it where the table should be displayed...

Comment: I've edited the question and included the entire View file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller isn't passing to the view what the view is expecting. You inject `query` and the view wants `$Webmasters`. Also the second array with `Dropdown` you added won't work. This should fix the issue:

```
public function postFilters() {
    $filt = Input::get('name'); // getting the value of the select
    $filters = Dropdown::getFilters();
    $query = DB::table('webmasters.top_pages')->where('filter',$filt)->limit(20)->get();
    return View::make('webmasters.filter', ['Webmasters'=>$query, 'Dropdown'=>$filters]);
}
```

#### Edit

Also you're using `Route::controller` with a controller function. You have to pass the controller class.

```
Route::controller('top_page', 'WebController');
```

It's important that you now use `top_page/filters` as URL for accessing the form. (and posting it)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I implemented the changes you suggested and now i'm getting a **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**, i've done some research on it and it appears to be a routing error. Do you know more about this and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working and i'm getting the same Exception. This might be a stupid question, but if i just pass the Controller Class, i dont understand how the controller methods will be chosen to be carried out if we do not specify how we want them to be called. I'm saying this because i want them to be called in a specific order.

Comment: The method name is built by the HTTP verb (POST, GET, etc) and the part after the URL you define... `POST /topPage/filters => WebController@postFilters` and `GET /topPage/foo => WebController@getFoo`

Comment: Still cant get it to work. Since passing the controller class to the restful route, i'm not even able to see the initial dropdown and submit button.

Comment: What's the url you're using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66103/discussion-between-tony-okoth-and-lukasgeiter).